# Quickly switching between run configurations in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, run-configuration

Two actions that I perform on a regular basis are "run my tests" and "run my application". Unfortunately, PyCharm uses the same keystroke (Shift+F10, i.e., "Run") for both, and that keystroke uses my "current" run/debug configuration. I have to do a separate step to change configurations, and that step involves finding and selecting the right option from a longish list -- and it also requires taking the time to think about *whether* I need to switch configurations.

With as frequently as I run both the tests and the app (I'm still relatively new to Python, so I want to check frequently to make sure I haven't broken anything), this is pretty cumbersome -- especially since my usual pattern is "run the tests, and if they pass, then run the app", so I'm switching configurations *all the time.*

**Is there an easier way to run a given configuration?** Ideally I'd like to be able to bind a single keystroke to "select and run my 'main.py' configuration", and another single keystroke to "select and run my 'py.test' configuration" -- but anything that means I'm not constantly hunting through a list of configurations would be helpful.

I've tried recording a macro that switches configurations and then runs, but the macro recorder doesn't actually record the "change configurations" step -- all that ends up in the macro is "run". And there doesn't appear to be a macro editor that would let me manually add that step.

I also know about the pop-up "select configuration and run" list (F9), but that still requires me to read which configuration is selected in the list, decide whether it's the one I want, and cursor up or down in the list before hitting Enter. It's not all that complicated, but it still interrupts my train of thought pretty thoroughly every time I do it. Running -- both the tests and the app -- should be simpler than this.

Comment: [Check this blog post](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/10/invoking-rundebug-actions-in-intellij-idea-9/) describing how to use quick Run/Debug configurations switcher.

Comment: That post describes the F9 popup list that I already mentioned in my question.

Comment: There is no faster way right now, vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-69968.

Answer (score -1):

I know this question is super old, but to anybody with the same problem.. here it is.

I had the same problem, because I had lots and lots of scripts on the same project, and I wanted to run a script individually.

What you need to do is, open up the script (by double-clicking), and then once it is open, right-click on anything, and you will see "run [the script]" with a green play button.

[here is the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CfhC.png)